# How to remove the existing polygons that overlaps on the newly edited polygons on the map, while redrawing the drawn items with new shapes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

Firstly, I'm new in using Leaflet.js and I hope someone here helps me out.

I am trying to drawn polygon shapes on Map. When i click on polygon, i can edit the polygon shape and also can see the details of the shape like name, type of polygon.

So, whenever a new polygon is drawn or edited, I tried to redraw the drawn items on map with newly created or updated values.

Here the issue is after an edit or create the newly drawn items are drawn above the previously drawn items.

*For Example*,If i edit the polygon shape for 5 times i have 5 layers on the Map. Please help me on how to remove the previous drawn items.

```
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
     if (!state.typeSelected) {
      props.types.map(({ key }) => {
      drawnItems[key] = new L.FeatureGroup();
      map.addLayer(drawnItems[key]);
      return true;
     });
    return { typeSelected: props.types[0] };
   }
   if (props.createAction.success === true || 
         props.editAction.success === true) {
         props.actionClear();
         return {
           ...state,
         popup: false,
         info: {
            ...state.info,
            id: '',
            name: '',
            geometry: ''
         }
       };
      }
     return state;
    }

     componentDidMount() {
       const { user, actionFetchTypes, actionFetch } = this.props;
       if (user.id) {
         actionFetch();
         actionFetchTypes();
         this.initializeMap();
       }
      }


      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { 
        user,
        surfaces,
        types,
        createAction,
        actionClear,
        editAction,
        deleteAction 
       } = this.props;
      const { allLayers, info, edit, layer} = this.state;
      const that = this;

       if (createAction.success === true &&  prevProps.createAction.success 
      === false) {
    this.setState({ popup: false, edit: true,
      allLayers: [{ key: -1, name: 'All Surfaces', color: '#CCCCCC' }]
     },() => {
      actionClear();
    });
   }

    if (editAction.success === true && prevProps.editAction.success === 
      false) {
      this.setState({ popup: false, edit: true, allLayers: [{ key: -1, 
       name: 'All Surfaces', color: '#CCCCCC' }]
      },() => {
      actionClear();
    });
   }
   if (!prevProps.user.id && user.id) {
     const { actionFetch, actionFetchTypes } = this.props;
     actionFetch();
     actionFetchTypes();
     this.initializeMap();
    }

   if ((allLayers.length === 1 && surfaces.length && types.length)) {
     let allLayers = [{ key: -1, name: this.props.intl.formatMessage({ 
     id: 'surface.allsurfaces' }), color: '#CCCCCC' }];
     surfaces.forEach((o) => {
      let l = L.geoJSON(o.geometry)._layers;
      [l] = Object.keys(l).map(ob => l[ob]);
      const customlayer = this.addPopupToLayer(o, l);

     map.addLayer(drawnItems[o.surface_type.id].addLayer(customlayer));
       l.on('click', (e) => {
        if (edit) {
         map.layer = e.target;
         map.eachLayer((layer) => {
           if (layer.editing && layer.editing.enabled()) {
             layer.editing.disable();
           }
         });
         e.target.editing.enable();
         that.setState({
          popup: true,
          detail: true,
          info: o,
          typeSelected: o.surface_type,
          editSurface: e.target
        });
      }
     });
     allLayers.push({
      key: o.surface_type.id,
      name: o.surface_type.name,
      color: o.surface_type.color
     });
   });
   allLayers = allLayers.filter(
     (l, index, self) => self.findIndex(
       t => t.key === l.key
     ) === index
   );
    this.setState({
      allLayers,
      counter: surfaces.length
      });
    }
  }

  addPopupToLayer = (surface, layer) => {
     const { surface_type: { color } } = surface;
     const customlayer = layer;
     customlayer.setStyle({
     fillColor: color,
     color,
     opacity: 1,
     fillOpacity: 0.48
    });
    return customlayer;
  };

 initializeMap() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    map = L.map('map', {
      center: [...user.location.coordinates].reverse(),
      zoom: 15,
      editable: true,
     });
     L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ type: 'satellite', maxZoom: 20 
   }).addTo(map);

  // creation callback for triggering form.
  const that = this;
  map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e) => {
    drawnItems[that.state.typeSelected.key].addLayer(e.layer);
    utils.toggleZooming(map, 'disable');
    that.setState({ popup: true, layer: e.layer });
  });
  map.on('draw:drawstart', (e) => {
    that.drawNewSurface()
  });
 }
```

Comment: Why you not only update the Latlngs? Or update the options / properties. You don't have to create everytime a new layer

Comment: @FalkeDesign I tried to update the latlngs/options rather than creating a layer whenever the polygon details are changed and if we click on it displayed the previous values. This is the reason why I wanted to create a layer with new Data.

Comment: can you pls post somewhere the full code.

Comment: @Falke Design posted the full code above can you pls check that

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand your code. Until you have no running online version at jsfiddle or something like that, i can't help you. But maybe you have to look at this line: `map.addLayer(drawnItems[o.surface_type.id].addLayer(customlayer));` there you adding the new layer. Try to remove first the same layer from the map